# Is there a way to all the li tags to have the same height?

Tags: css

I want my `li` tags to have the same height (based on the higher li), but I also want them to be responsive. I was thinking of setting a fixed height, but in lower resolutions the text is almost attached to the border of the `li`. Also, each `li` is a carousel item from [`hooper`](https://baianat.github.io/hooper/).

You can see that the first carousel item has a height, and the next item has a lower height. I want both of them to have the same height based on the height of the carousel item of Rock and Rolls since it's the highest `li`. Tried with flex on each `li`, tried with `min-height: 100%` and still nothing

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-leaf-lci7ix?file=/src/main.js

Comment: Please include an [example].

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-leaf-lci7ix?file=/src/main.js

Comment: @SergioRamirez your sandbox doesn't seem to showcase your current problem, please update it.

Comment: It does actually. The `li` tags do not have the same height, and I want them to have the height based on the highest `li`